# changing z index on div after animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, z-index

I have 3 divs
1 set to z-index1 (background image)
1 set to z-index5  (plain div with text and links)
1 set to z-index10 (foreground image)

The z-index5 slides up between two other divs and stops.  However, it has links in it that are not clickable because its under the foreground image (which is a .png that is mostly see through)

My question is, how do I get the z-index to shift forward once the animation stopped so the links become clickable?  Here is what I have thus far but its not working.  The animation plays correctly but the zindex is not seeming to shift above the foreground.  Thanks in advance.

Page in quesiton: www.titanstudio.net/about.html

The entire jquery code which animates another small div, preloads the images and hides the divs until the images are loaded.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#PageTitle').fadeIn(500,function(){
       $(this).animate({"left" : "100px"}, 1000);
     });
    $(function() {
        $('#contentcontain').animate({ marginTop: 40 }, 7000, function() {
            $(this).css({ zIndex: 15 });
        });
    });
    $('#undersplash').show();
    $('#oversplash').show();
});
```

Comment: fyi, i guess correct property is `z-index` not `'zIndex`'.

Comment: It's either `.css('z-index', 15);` or `.css({zIndex : 15});`

Comment: I was too slow to answer, but here: http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/tcYA8/

Comment: Joonas uses ZIndex in his jsfiddle and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('#contentcontain').animate({'margin-top': '10px'}, 7000, function() {
        $(this).css('z-index', '15');
    });     
});
```

Comment: This is not working either.. Im wondering if its the foreground image that is messing it up.

Comment: @JamieCollingwood - Check the elements with a DOM inspector to see if the z-index actually changes, and if it does, something else is the problem?

Comment: Ya.. thanks for the suggestion, don't know why I didn't go to that.  Dom tool revealed I had the middle div nested inside the background div..  Took it out so its not nested and works great now... sorry all for overlooking the obvious first. =(

Comment: On a side note.. $(this).css({ zIndex: 15 }); works as well as 'z-index'  Thanks for the help everyone!